# Confusion in accessing class attribute without self - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that we can access class attributes with `self` or the `class` name.

But I am bit confused why the following also works

```
class Crazy(object):
  VERSION = 1
  def __init__(self, version=VERSION):
    print version
```

But this doesn't

```
class Crazy(object):
  VERSION = 1
  def __init__(self):
    print VERSION
```

Comment: You couldn't access it **with** `self` in the first snippet, because the method definition runs at class definition time, before you've finished creating the class and *definitely* before you can have created an instance.

Comment: But I can do `version=Crazy.VERSION`, right ?

Comment: *Where*? Not inside the method parameter list, as the name Crazy doesn't exist yet either. Only inside the method body

Comment: Oh yes !! But why does it work with `VERSION` in parameter list but not inside `__init__()` ?

Comment: That's just how scope works. The class attributes are in scope inside the class definition, but *not* inside the method bodies.

Comment: Oh ok !! So you mean, that the class method `__init__` is still in the phase of being defined in `def __init__(...)`. Basically, we don't have class ready yet, hence `VERSION` works and not `Crazy.VERSION` . But inside `__init__(...)`, class is already defined and instance is being created hence accessing `VERSION` with `self/Crazy.` will work

Comment: @jonrsharpe "not inside the method bodies"  That's apparently how it works in _python_ (which is imo kinda strange) . Not in c/jvm languages afaik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class definition, i.e. the block inside `class ...:`, is evaluated like any regular Python code block. Just at the end of the `class` block, every local name which was defined inside that block becomes part of the class' `__dict__`. The `class` syntax is more or less just syntactic sugar over:

```
Crazy = type('Crazy', (object,), {'VERSION': 1, ...})
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type.

Given this, you'd expect this to work, right?

```
VERSION = 1

def foo(bar=VERSION):
    print(bar)
```

(Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133013/476) for more explanation on its behaviour.)

Inside a `class` block this works exactly the same way, with the only special behaviour that you're not creating *global* names, but names which will become the class' `__dict__`.

The relevant paragraph in the documentation is here:

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see [Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)), using a newly created local namespace and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains mostly function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved. A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary. The class name is bound to this class object in the original local namespace.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

After the class is defined though, that implicit namespace doesn't exist anymore, so this doesn't work:

```
def __init__(self):
    print(VERSION)
```

The scoping rules follow the regular lookup chain:

- is it a local variable inside the same function?
- is it a nonlocal variable in a surrounding function?
- is it a global variable?

None of these are true, since `VERSION` is just an attribute of `Crazy` at this point, so is only accessible as `Crazy.VERSION` or `self.VERSION`, the latter of which actually also doesn't exist and falls back onto its own lookup chain and traverses up to `Crazy.VERSION`.