Why do class methods shadowing names from outer scope in python class method type hints?
For example:
In [4]: In [17]: class X:
   ...:     def not_shadow(self, x: list[int]):
   ...:         pass
   ...: 
   ...:     def list(self):
   ...:          list()
   ...: 
   ...:     def shadow_by_X_list_method(self, x: list[int]):
   ...:         pass
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 class X:
      2     def not_shadow(self, x: list[int]):
      3         pass

Cell In[4], line 8, in X()
      5 def list(self):
      6      list()
----> 8 def shadow_by_X_list_method(self, x: list[int]):
      9     pass

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

I expected that class function names would only be available as members of self variable.

Type hints are evaluated in the scope of the class body, not the function. Method names are in that scope.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265940/476

Function names are not special in any way. A def statement is just another form of assignment.

This is a quirk of the scoping rules!
While perhaps surprising, as @jonsharpe notes in a comment, this behavior is the same as everywhere in Python and allows later methods and their arguments to refer to earlier methods in general
In their example, they note @property, which adds additional methods directly to the wrapped method
Abridged from the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property.getter
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter            # <-- property of earlier x
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

